# Is docker caching useless when RUN is involved?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-layer

Consider this example from [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/#how-can-i-use-the-cache-efficiently):

> ```Dockerfile
> # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
> FROM node
> WORKDIR /app
> COPY package.json yarn.lock .    # Copy package management files
> RUN npm install                  # Install dependencies
> COPY . .                         # Copy over project files
> RUN npm build                    # Run build
> ```
>
> By installing dependencies in earlier layers of the Dockerfile, there
> is no need to rebuild those layers when a project file has changed.

Which layers can be skipped here?

By my understanding, `npm` command is black-box for docker,
so docker doesn't know what `npm`'s inputs are and what will it produce.
If so, then docker has to always run `npm install` and `npm build` commands, which means caching is useless here.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Docker doesn't know what the RUN commands will do, but it assumes they're pure in terms of the preceding layers. Read the big note boxout about apt-get on the page you're linking to, for example.

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe So docker will cache `RUN curl https://bbc.com -o bbc.txt` as well?

Comment: Make a prediction, try it out and compare.

Answer (score 0):

> Is docker caching useless when RUN is involved?

No.

> Which layers can be skipped here?

All.

> so docker doesn't know what npm's inputs are and what will it produce

Docker exactly knows that - the input is all the files and the image produced from earlier stages, and the output are all the modifications made to the files in the image. The modifications are saved as a new layer.

Answer (score 0):

> […] docker doesn't know what `npm`'s inputs are and what will it produce.

Docker indeed doesn't know what `npm install` means (e.g., you might configure your terminal to [alias `npm install` to `echo 42`](https://chat.openai.com/share/7cced1ff-7152-41f8-a3f7-a90ea0e8164a) or anything else). But it does know that running it does not depend on any files.

"What will it produce" depends on its inputs (as @jonrsharpe also said in the comments). So, if inputs aren't changed, the outputs aren't changed either, Docker can infer that.

Compare it with, for example, `COPY package.json yarn.lock .` which *does* depend on the contents of `package.json` and `yarn.lock`. Conversely, if either of those files is changed, then the `COPY …` command is re-applied, and thus the subsequent `RUN npm install` is re-applied as well.

So, to answer the titular question:

> Is docker caching useless when RUN is involved?

It's rather the opposite: `RUN`-ing side-effect'y scripts is useless when Docker caching is involved.